# C# html agility pack get elements by class name

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to get all the divs that their class contains a certain word:

```
<div class="hello mike">content1</div>
<div class="hello jeff>content2</div>
<div class="john">content3</div>
```

I need to get all the divs that their class contains the word "hello".
Something like this:

```
resultContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='hello']"))
```

how can i do it with agility pack?

Answer (score 45):

I got it:

```cs
resultContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(@class, 'hello')]")
```

Answer (score 26):

As of version v1.6.5 of Html Agility Pack, it contains `.HasClass("class-name")` extension method.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes =
    htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants(0)
        .Where(n => n.HasClass("class-name"));
```

Comment: Above is 5 times faster than the most popular answer - though i used document.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.HasClass(....

Answer (score 12):

I'm sure because there're multiple classes in your div, that doesn't work. You can try this instead:

```
resultContent.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(d => d.Attributes["class"].Value.Contains("hello"));
```

Comment: Has one drawback as opposed to the other answer: it throws an exception if there's a div without `class`. Use this instead: `.Where(d => d.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains("hello"));`

Answer (score 1):

as you have specified that the class has to contain a certain word, the following will ensure that the word is:

- at the start of the string and followed by a space
- or in the middle of the string and surrounded by whitespace
- or at the end of the string and preceded by a space
- or the only class name in the class attribute

It does so by comparing the value of the class attribute surrounded by spaces with the specified word (`hello`) surrounded by spaces. This is to avoid false positives like `class="something-hello-something"`

```
resultContent.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' hello ')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load(filePath);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//div[@class='hello']")
 {
    //code
 }
```

Comment: Doesn' work. OP tries to find alll divs where the class _contains_ a word as substring, for example `hello`. You are selecting only divs where the class **is** `hello`