# Get Element by class name in Html document with Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to get an element by class name with html agility pack.the element is inside a lot of other elements, so i can't get element like:

`//section[@class='class1']/div[@class='class2']/div[@class='class3']/`

I Want to get my element `<p class="title">My Text</p>` directly.

I get the body of html document with the following code:

```
var body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# html agility pack get elements by class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711680/c-sharp-html-agility-pack-get-elements-by-class-name)

Comment: @KJSR this is not my answer

Answer (score -1):

Simply, try this code:

```cs
HtmlNode myParagraph = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//p[@class='title']");
```

I hope this helps you.