# C# Regex replace text in nested HTML tags with asterisks

Tags: c#, regex

I need to replace a text match inside a HTML Tag (not the HTML Content) with asterisks. This HTML Tag might also be nested. For example:

`<span class='lorem'>Lorem ipsum</span>`

The result should be:

`<span class='*****'>Lorem ipsum</span>`

Or for nested ones:

`<p class='lorem'>Lorem<span id='ipsum'>ipsum</span></p>`

The result should be:

`<p class='*****'>Lorem<span id='*****'>ipsum</span></p>`

I've created a method for that, but it works only for unnested HTML Tags:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Sanitizes the source by replacing any value matching the param text within HTML Tag with asterisks.
        /// This ensures that only HTML content will be considered.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The source to look for Html Tags.</param>
        /// <param name="text">The text to be looked for in the source.</param>
        /// <returns>Source with sanitized HTML, if any. If no HTML was found returns the source itself.</returns>
        private static string SanitizeSource(string s, string text)
        {
            var regex = new Regex("<(.*)>(.*?)</(.*?)>");
            var m = regex.Match(s);

            if (!m.Success) { 
                return s;
            }

            var tagStart = m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(text, new string('*', text.Length), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            var tagContent = m.Groups[2].Value;
            var tagEnd = m.Groups[3].Value;

            var newSource = $"<{tagStart}>{tagContent}</{tagEnd}>";

            return newSource;
        }
```

I thought to call this method recursively to always look for nested HTML Tags, but I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way?

**EDIT:**

Based on the answer, the code above became:

```
        private static string SanitizeSource(string s, string text)
        {
            var result = Regex.Replace(s, "(?<==('|\"))(.*?)(?=(\\1))", new string('*', text.Length));

            return result;
        }
```

There are still some edge cases which I'm working on, for example for the string:

`"<img src="http://lorem.png" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."`

It should become:

`"<img src="http://*****.png" />Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."`

Currently the pattern is removing everything after the equals sign `=`.

**EDIT:**

After looking for a clean solution and trying it myself I found out that trying to handle HTML strings with RegExp is very prone to errors. Although I've found before some links at StackOverflow I was still not sure if that was good or don't. Indeed [HtmlAgilityPack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) was my best option.

Comment: You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @ChristianBaumann thanks, but I don't see where I'm parsing HTML. This a string matching.

Comment: is this on a html file or html from a website, or nested in html ? if so, regex is not really suitable

Comment: The more elegant way would be to use  HtmlAgilityPack. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36711680/c-sharp-html-agility-pack-get-elements-by-class-name for how to find by class name.   HtmlAgilityPack can also find by id.

Comment: It comes from a string input from a REST Api. I‘m not parsing anything and I don’t need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to match text between `='` and `'>` then replace it with asterisks.

```
(?<=='|=")(.+?)(?='|"|'>)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tVIAN4/6)

Comment: And if you can have more attributes and quotes - (?<==('|"))(.+?)(?=(\1)) use the same pattern from @Ankit just little changed, and then you can call Regex.Replace withhin

Comment: @Ankit thank you, this is already a good approach, but still not working if there are more than one attribute, for example: `<span class='lorem' id='ipsum'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>`. It removes `id='ipsum'`. Here the example: https://regex101.com/r/tVIAN4/2

Comment: The tag has to be kept as it was, but every match should be replaced by asterisks. It might also be a `data-some-attribute=word_to_be_replaced`

Comment: @DAG You're welcome, I'll see if I can edit the regex to match your second case.

Comment: @DAG check if this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/tVIAN4/3) satisfies all the test cases.

Comment: Yes, and you can use it like: Regex
                .Matches(response, "(?<==('|\"))(.*?)(?=(\\1))")
                .Where(x => x.Success)
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(x => response = Regex.Replace(response, x, new string('*', x.Length)));

Comment: That is it. Thanks.

Comment: Most Welcome :)

Comment: Another edge case: `<img src="http://lorem.png" />`

The regex will remove the whole content after `=` and I need to remove only the matching word `lorem`. I don't think this is something we can solve in one single expression?

Comment: We can get the whole text between double quotes i.e. `http://lorem.png` using the already posted RegEx, but to match the specific word `lorem` here a new RegEx can be created to match to match file names in web address in a tag.